# Heroku: could not read from remote repository

Tags: heroku, permissions

I created an app and got on Heroku, everything worked fine until I had to format the computer.
I had to update the app and I can not synchronize the folders.
I Heroku Keys and saw that it appeared the network name before formatting, so I removed with heroku Keys: remove ... and added a new key with ssh-keygen-t rsa.
I also entered the git file and delete the lines in "heroku remote", but neither worked. After much testing I realized that in the same file in the fetch line did not appear the name of the app, instead put heroku, I changed it, but still not working.
I always show the same errors, although I already created a SSH public key: public key C :/ / .ssh / id-rsa.pub

```
permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure You have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Even I created a new app, but appear the same mistakes, it is clear that the problem is due to formatting the computer, something does not match and does not let me sync files in any app.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Heroku is missing your SSH public key, you just need to add it using this command:

```
$ heroku keys:add
```

If you need to generate new SSH keys too, [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku) covers both of these topics.